# SonarQube 6.2 - Export issues

Tags: sonarqube

I am using the latest SonarQube 6.2. 
They have moved out the reporting module into a commercial governance module.
Now I cannot find any way to export the issues into some report, or filter the issues based on set of classes.

The File filter provided on Issues page, is not providing the full list of files, nor does it have any search option to filter the issues based on a given file name.

My basic need is to filter and view the issues for a given file. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the WS [api/issues/search](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/search) and give the componentKeys parameter